# How do I interpret this residual plot (lmer) and the changes introduced by including an interaction effect?

Tags: lme4-nlme, residuals

I am currently using linear mixed models for the first time in a small repeated measures experiment, and I feel like I am missing out on some basics in diagnostic plots.

I want to model a labeling skill using dprime as a DV. The data I collected is slightly right skewed - from what I see in relevant papers, this is mainly due to my sample size being too small, in bigger studies on the same topic this isn't an issue.

This was my original model, with there being a slight trend in the residual plot and the Q-Q plot having a pretty nasty tail.

```
lmm.main <- lmer(dprime ~ strength + treatment + stance + congruence + gender + age + (1|id))
```

[image: Original Model]

I found a potential interaction effect between stance and congruence, which turned out to be very relevant as a predictor. However, I'm not sure if my model assumptions are now even "more violated" (is that a thing?) than before. My residual plot shows a clearly upward sloping trend that I can not "log-transform away".

What is the right way to think about residual plots and trends in an exploratory analysis with few participants, and how can I potentially improve the normality of my residuals? Would you consider the second or first model "better" when it comes to fulfilling the assumptions for LMMs - or would you consider both a no-go?

```
lmm.int <- lmer(dprime ~ strength + treatment + stance * congruence + stance + congruence + gender + age + (1|id))
```

[image: Interaction]

Comment: I look at this and it seems pretty darn good. Yes, the ends of the qqplot deviate away from the optimum 1-1 line, but it's real world data - I'd be pretty happy if that's my model. If anything, the deviation at the top right looks better for the `int` model than for the original model. If you are still worried about skew, you could look at things like skewed distribution, e.g. a gamma mixed model, which you could implement in `glmmTMB`.

Comment: You just made my day. I am new to "real-world data" and never know when I should worry just from the plots. My shapiro-wilk test said the residuals were likely not normally distributed and I was quite worried.  :)

Comment: Unless there's a specific reason why you _must_ have normality, I wouldn't worry about doing a formal hypothesis test for normality, a visual check is fine. Most real life distributions are not normal (even if they are very close), so when you have a large enough dataset the test becomes significant and you worry necessarily. If it's close enough to normality, your model results will be approximately valid, which is all you can ever hope for in statistics most of the time. I think your model looks good. Would recommend R `DHARMa` package for more mixed model diagnostics tho esp. w/ GLMMs!

Comment: `DHARMa` is good; `performance::model_check()` is good too.